# How to make many definitions available as some kind of mode?

Tags: key-bindings, unicode

I've written a Vim script that inserts Unicode mathematical notation into what I'm editing. It's basically a few hundred lines of code that look like `:map! \bbq ℚ`.

Sometimes I want to enable all of these definitions together. And sometimes I want to switch them all back off again. Really I want some kind of mode where they are enabled. But I'd like to switch them on and off while editing other types of file, like C++ source or plain text. What's the best way to organize this? Do I need to write a few hundred `unmap`s? Or is there some way of undoing a whole lot of mappings in bulk? Can I wrap this up in some kind of mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need those mappings only for certain kinds of files, define them in a script separate from your `~/.vimrc` and as *buffer-local* mappings:

```
:map! <buffer> \bbq ℚ
```

You can then `:source path/to/script.vim` on demand. Alternatively, by putting the script into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_mappings.vim`, they will be automatically loaded whenever Vim's filetype detection (cp. `:help filetype`) recognizes `{filetype}` (e.g. `tex` for Latex documents).

If you still need to remove the mappings for the particular buffer, there's no way around defining corresponding `:unmap <buffer>` commands, or maybe using the hack of `:set paste` (which disables all mappings and has other side effects).

Comment: Could also use an expression mapping with some conditional. e.g. `map! <expr> \bbq get(g:, 'use_mappings', 1) ? 'ℚ' : '\bbq'`. Now you can do `:let g:use_mappings = 0` to turn off the mappings. I also feel like these mappings should be abbreviations instead of mappings.

Comment: @PeterRincker I like to be able to search for α say by typing /\alpha. That works with `map!` but not `ab`.